# How to find normal boiling temperature if vapor pressure is known in any temperature?

Tags: organic-chemistry, boiling-point

I can calculate the vapor pressure of the Acetone at any given temperature using the Antoine equation. Is it possible to find the normal boiling temperature of the Acetone?

(It has to be done by just using the vapor pressure at various temperatures without using any constant specific to Acetone)

Comment: The boiling temperature is simply the temperature at which the vapor pressure equals the ambient pressure.  That's because the vapor pressure equaling the ambient pressure is what allows the liquid to boil.